# template function argument explicit type declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr, sfinae

I have a list of operator overloads, and I found that they are not acting in the way that I want them to. I reduced the problematic code to a couple lines to simulate the problem. I have a couple template type aliases to help compile time decision making, a template function (an operator in the working code, but here just a generic function), and a class called `var` that takes in two template parameters, an `unsigned int` and a `bool` (`true` = known var, `false` = unknown var, just mentioning this so that the naming convention in the following code snippet makes sense). Here is the code.

```
template<typename T>
using is_known = typename std::is_same<T, const var<T::ID, true> >::type;

template<typename T>
using is_unknown = typename std::conditional<is_known<T>::value, std::false_type, std::true_type>::type;

template<typename T>
using UK_if_UK = typename std::enable_if<is_unknown<T>::value, T>::type;

template<typename unknown_check_LHS, typename unknown_check_RHS>
constexpr const two_param_type<UK_if_UK<unknown_check_LHS>, UK_if_UK<unknown_check_RHS> > func(const unknown_check_LHS& lhs, const unknown_check_RHS& rhs)
{
    return two_param_type<unknown_check_LHS, unknown_check_RHS>
    (//generic construction goes here, unimportant...);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr const var<0u,true> firstvar(123);
    constexpr const var<1u,true> secondvar(456);

    func(firstvar,secondvar);
    func<std::decltype(firstvar),std::decltype(secondvar)>(firstvar,secondvar);
}
```

The two calls to `func()` seem identical to me, and they should both fail (in the working code there are other options once this function SFINAEs out). However, only the second call, where I explicitly declare the types, does the compiler throw an error. It compiles the first call to `func()` perfectly, and even worse, it operates and returns with type "known" (`var<(some unsigned),true>`), even though the type alias in the return type should SFINAE the function out of overload resolution. I am using operators, so explicitly declaring the type is not an option for me. More importantly, however, I want to know why the function is not SFINAEing out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: The specific error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'func(const var<0u, true>&, const var<1u, true>&)'
```

Also, I have tested `is_known`, `is_unknown`, and `UK_if_UK` to work properly, so no need to test those. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The two calls to func seem identical to me

Wrong.

They are different.

It's a constness problem.

With

```
constexpr const var<0u,true> firstvar(123);
constexpr const var<1u,true> secondvar(456);
```

and the signature of `func()` as follows

```
template<typename unknown_check_LHS, typename unknown_check_RHS>
constexpr /* ... */ func (const unknown_check_LHS & lhs,
                          const unknown_check_RHS & rhs)
```

calling

```
func(firstvar,secondvar);
```

the types, `unknown_check_LHS` and `unknown_check_RHS`, are detected as `var<0u, true>` and `var<1u, true>` respectively.

Please observe: `var<0u, true>` and `var<1u, true>`, not `const var<0u, true>` and `const var<1u, true>`.

On the contrary, explicating the types as follows

```
func<decltype(firstvar), decltype(secondvar)>(firstvar,secondvar);
```

(and please: `decltype()`, not `std::decltype()`), `unknown_check_LHS` and `unknown_check_RHS` are explicated as `const var<0u, true>` and `const var<1u, true>` respectively.

Observe that now the types are **constant**.

Observe how is defined `is_know`

```
template<typename T>
using is_known = typename std::is_same<T, const var<T::ID, true> >::type;
```

It compare the type `T` with a constant type.

So, in the first case (with template types not-constant), `is_known` is false; in the second case (with constant template types), it's true.

Comment: Thank you, I never would have thought this was the problem. My previous solution was to move the alias calls into the function parameter list rather than the return type declaration, which ultimately worked, but knowing why the previous way didn't work is very helpful. Thanks